# NSString object compare nil

Tags: cocoa, object-code

so I have NSString object that I declare so :

NSString *XMLOut;

Now this object can be empty or non empty.

How can I see it ?

```
If ([XMLOut isEqual:nil]) {
    NSLog(@"XMLOut is empty");
} else {
    NSLog(@"XMLOut is not empty");
  }
```

is it correct ?

Comment: Use `if ([XMLOut length] == 0) NSLog(@"XMLOut is empty");`

Answer (score 1):

> Now this object can be empty or non empty.

Empty is not the same thing as `nil`.

An empty string is still a string. It has a `length` (zero), you can append other strings to it, include it in strings to be joined by some character, etc.

`nil` is no object. There is no string there. There is nothing there. It has no length, nor any other properties.

So, do you mean “I want to compare my string, which may be `nil`, to determine whether it is `nil`”, or “I want to compare my string, which may be *empty*, to determine whether it is empty”?

#### Testing whether it's `nil`

The documentation for the `isEqual:` method says:

> - `anObject`: The object to be compared to the receiver. May be `nil`, in which case this method returns `NO`.

So, if `XMLOut` is not `nil`, `[XMLOut isEqual:nil]` is guaranteed to return `NO`.

But what if it's not `nil`?

Messages to `nil` return basically every kind of zero (excepting structures and the like), which includes `NO`.

Which means that `[XMLOut isEqual:nil]` will *always* be `NO`:

- If `XMLOut` is `nil`, the answer is always `NO` no matter the question.
- If `XMLOut` is not `nil`, the answer is `NO` because no string is equal to `nil`.

Use the `==` operator instead. `XMLOut == nil` will correctly test whether `XMLOut` is `nil`.

#### Testing whether it's empty

As mah already told you in their comment, ask the string for its `length`.

- If `XMLOut` is `nil`, the answer is always zero no matter the question.
- If `XMLOut` is an empty string, its length is zero.
- If `XMLOut` is any other string, its length is greater than zero.

Comment: Ok, I use this code for this test : 
If ([XMLOut length] == 0) {NSLog(@"XMLOut is empty);)